# How to set color for values in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Searched through the documentation but couldn't find anything that implemented correctly. I have a graph at the moment but I want to change the color of the line if it goes over a certain amount. [Graph Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkeT2.png) In the example I have linked, it shows a line drawn through the values from 10. I would like this line (the one going through the chart) and the color of the line in the chart to change color over 10. Is this possible? Using MPAndroidChart. I have one dataset at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You just need a simple logic.

```
List<Integer> colors = ...;
List<Entry> entries = ...;

for(...) {

   entries.add(...);

   if(entries.get(i).getVal() > 10) 
       colors.add(customcolor);
   else 
       colos.add(othercolor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With LineDataSet.setColors() you can add a list of colors. Each color entry is for one data entry.
'
The trick is to calculate intermediate values for crossing the border.

Everytime I add a data entry, i call this method

```
private fun addDiffValue(newEntry : Entry){
    val last = recordedValues[2].last()
    val limit = 50f
    if(last.y < limit && newEntry.y > limit  ){
        val gradient = (newEntry.y - last.y) / (newEntry.x - last.x)
        val x_border = last.x + ((limit - last.y) / gradient)
        recordedValues[2].add(Entry(x_border, limit))
        diffColors.add(Color.LTGRAY)
        diffColors.add(Color.RED)
    }
    // Vorher größer, jetzt kleiner
    else if(last.y > limit && newEntry.y < limit) {
        val gradient = (newEntry.y - last.y) / (newEntry.x - last.x)
        val x_border = last.x + ((limit - last.y) / gradient)
        recordedValues[2].add(Entry(x_border, limit))
        diffColors.add(Color.RED)
        diffColors.add(Color.LTGRAY)
    }else if(last.y > limit ){
        diffColors.add(Color.RED)
    } else {
        diffColors.add(Color.LTGRAY)
    }
    recordedValues[2].add(newEntry)
}
```

It is important to say, that I start with `recordedValues[2].add(Entry(0f,0f))`, otherwise  `last()` would throw an error.

I create the LineDataSet and add the colors:

```
val dataSet3 = LineDataSet(recordedValues[2], "My Label")
dataSet3.setColors(diffColors)
```

As you can see in this screenshot, all values above 50 are red.

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is the 'recordedValues[2]' that is used in the 'addDiffValue()' function?

Comment: 'recordedValues[2]' is of type `ArrayList<Entry>` and diffColors is of type `ArrayList<Int>`.
So the new entry (A) is compared to the last entry (B), and if it intersects `limit` an entry (C) is added between them. This is neccessary, because a color is used from one entry to the next. so you have grey from B to C and red from C to A.

Comment: Hi, I have tried adding the above code. But it's not working for me. In my graph, the line disappeared after I set colors array. Is there anything that I missed?. Could you please help me with this. I have tried the following way. 1) I have tried looping my existing List of Entry with this function to get a new list. 2) Then I have set the new list as dataset. 3) I have set colors as the diffcolors generated after running this function.

Comment: What you tried sounds right, but I do not see your code, so I can not tell you, where the error is.  
Check in your debugger, that you have one entry more than you have colors, and manually check if the coordinates are right (no x/y swap).

Comment: Hi, sorry that was my mistake. Now your code works like a charm. Thanks for sharing it. Kudos.