# MPAndroidChart gradient line depending on dataset values

Tags: android, gradient, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm currently working on a project using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and i want to make a LineChart to represent data per hour. I need this chart to have gradient line depending on values on yAxis.

[image: current graph]

eg. In the graph above i want the line to change the color when yAxis values are >50.
I didn't find any solution to my problem, so any suggestions or examples are welcome

Comment: You want this check on last available value or on all values?

Comment: @UmerFarooq i want this to be on every value on the chart. eg from 02:00 to 03:00 the line should change color from green to red, then from 03:00 to 04:00 and 04:00 to 05:00 to remain the same color (as both values are above 50), then from 05:00 to 06:00 become green again etc.

Comment: @yakamuki Have you created the following grap..Please add the solution , if you have any thanks

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha i couldn't find a solution to make the line gradient, but i did something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177507/5348018)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had  to face the exact same problem, and the solution was to define a linear gradient and apply it as a shader, like this:

*(Warning: You'll notice that the code looks funny, and that is because it is xamarin code (i.e: C#, not java nor kotlin), but you'll be able to translate it easily, mostly you have to change the PascalCase for camelCase, and change some properties into setters and getter or vice versa, just use your IDE's intellisense)*

```
[set your line chart, add the dataset, etc]
...
var gradient = new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 0f, 100f, 
               [your first color], [your second color], 
               Shader.TileMode.Clamp);
var paint = vh.Chart.Renderer.PaintRender;
paint.SetShader(gradient);
...
[set axis, labels, grid, etc]
...
lineChart.Invalidate(); //this is to refresh the chart on the screen, you may need it or not depending on your code
```

In the code above you just have to add your colors, and you may want to change the gradient direction (I'm using a vertical gradient here) by changing the 4 first floats when creating the linearGradient. One typical change is to set the y0 = 0 and y1 = the height of your chart, for example. You have to play with the values according to your layout.

The result for this code is something like:

[image]

Of course, I'm showing it with a repeated sample dataset, that's why you are seeing two cards with the same line.

**UPDATE:**
I understand what you want to achieve, and with the code above you can do it. You will need some calculations, of course, but you can set the "trigger" where the color starts to change at any Y coordinate you want.

For example, in this first picture, I've used the coordinates 0,0,0,100
(Please keep in mind that I'm showing you the last value in dp, but in the real code I am translating it to the equivalent in pixels according to the device's resolution. It is roughly the height of my chart)

[image: the gradient generated using 0,0,0,100]

And in the following image, I've changed it to 0,0,0,50:

[image: the gradient generated with 0,0,0,50]

As you can see, you have full control over how the gradient is shown just by changing the 4 values. (or, in my case, just one of them)
(You may notice that I've changed the colors as per my design, it has nothing to do with the threshold)

Comment: well that seems correct, but in my case i have to represent some medical data (stress, hr, etc..) and i have a threshold for each value that is not static. The threshold for each data can be changes any time, so the line has to adjust the color changing depending on the current threshold. Thats my problem, how to define in a linearGradient the limit where the color changing starts

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are using for-loop to populate your data. In list you need to populate a list of colors for every value and then use `lineDataSet.setColors(listOfColors)`.

```
List<Integer> listOfColors = new List<>();
for(i= 0; i<dataEntries.size(); i++){
    //Logic for colors
    if(i<= dataEntries.size()-1){ //Otherwise app will crash on last index
        if(dataEntries.get(i+1).y > 50)
            listOfColors.add(Color.GREEN);
        else
            listOfColors.add(Color.RED);
}
```

Then in the last

```
lineDataSet.setColors(listOfColors)
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: so far so good. but i want the line color to be gradient, and i want to change the color of the line only when its over value 50 on yAxis. eg. if i have a point in y=20 and the next point is in y=80, then with your code example, the line from 20 to 80 will be painted red. Ideally i want the line to remain green until it passes the 50 threshold on yAxis and then become gradient red till y=80

Comment: this is not possible with MPChart. For this you'll need to create your customized graph

Comment: this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177507/5348018

Comment: i found a snippet of code that makes the line gradient 

Paint paint = chart.getRenderer().getPaintRender();
        int height = 100;
        LinearGradient linGrad = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
                ContextCompat.getColor((MainActivity)mContext, R.color.stressNormal),
                ContextCompat.getColor((MainActivity)mContext, R.color.stressHigh),
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(linGrad);

but i don't know if there is a way to modify this so to change the color after the value of 50.

Comment: @UmerFarooq Can you please add the whole code to achive the above task. Please help me on it,Thanks