# Can set multiple color in char

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

i found similar problem to my, and i try to solve my problem with those answers, but i dont work
I want to set line color for specific value. Based on similar question i write this code

```
       public LineChart addChartEntry(float YValue, long date, boolean pauseMode, ChartColor chartColor) {
        counter++;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf.applyPattern("mm");
        min = sdf.format(new Date(date));
        sdf.applyPattern("ss.SSSS");
        String stringDate = sdf.format(new Date(date));
        float time = Float.parseFloat(stringDate);
//        if (entries.size() > 70 && !pauseMode) {
//            dataset.removeFirst();
//            colors.remove(0);
//        }
        dataset.addEntry(new Entry(time, YValue));
        dataset.notifyDataSetChanged();
        data.notifyDataChanged();
        colors.add(chartColor.getColor());
        chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(0);
        chart.setVisibleXRange(0, 4f);
        //chart.moveViewToX(dataset.getEntryCount() - 6);
        chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        chart.invalidate();
        return chart;
    }
```

also i add at the beginning of display graph

```
        dataset.setColors(colors);
```

### [How to set color for values in MPAndroidChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707532/how-to-set-color-for-values-in-mpandroidchart)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my own solution. I post it if someone will also need help. To solve this problem I just add LineSet. So I if need to change the color of Line, I just add new lines